# Running Sharepoint Information Worker Demo Machine on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to get the 2010 Information Worker Demonstration and Evaluation Virtual Machine (SP1)

https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417

working on VirtualBox. The host OS is Ubuntu 10.10

The information worker .vhd image seems to work alright by using the 'trick' of mounting it on  the ide controller as opposed to sata in VirtualBox.

The machine starts and generally everything seems OK, except there is some sort of issue around networking. Now my knowledge in this area is very limited, does anyone know what settings are needed to get this demo virtual machine working in VirtualBox?

Ideally I'd like to be able to start up the 'B' virtual machine as well and have it connect to the Sharepoint server on machine 'A'